# Nesting If statements to detect request value in Django views

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-views

I am trying to get  third button to work on a simple app I am making. I set up if statements to detect the value of the request for two buttons, but I am getting stuck on how to configure the logic statement to get a third parameter through.

My issue is that I need to have the form filled with any data before the subscriptions button will work properly. When the form is blank the app will indicate the form needs to be filled out. I am not familiar with javascript to have the buttons run from that. My hope is that I can learn how to configure the if statement to have the subscriptions call work without the form being filled out.

Below is the UI as and the views.py def. The Amount and Delete functions work fine. It is just the subscription button that won't work until I put literally any data into the two text fields fields.

[image]

```
    def usage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                    if request.POST.get('subscription') == 'Subscription':
                        dt = datetime.today()
                        month = dt.month
                        year = dt.year
                        day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
                        eom = str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)
                        anchor = int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(eom, "%m/%d/%Y").timetuple()) + 68400)
                        cust_list = json.loads(str(stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)))

                        for item in cust_list['data']:

                            try:
                                print(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id'], item['email'], item['id'])

                            except:

                                stripe.Subscription.create(
                                    customer=item['id'],
                                    items=[{'plan': 'plan_DFnNVzXKJ2w0Ad'}],
                                    billing_cycle_anchor=anchor,
                                )

                    if request.POST.get('delete') == 'Delete':
                        cust_info = custinfo.objects.all()
                        cust_info.delete()
                        all_custinfo_items = custinfo.objects.all()

                    else:
                        Sub_ID = form.cleaned_data['Sub_ID']
                        amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']


                        stripe_data = stripe.SubscriptionItem.list(subscription=Sub_ID)

                        sub_item = stripe_data["data"][0]["id"]

                        stripe.UsageRecord.create(
                            quantity=amount,
                            timestamp=int(time.time()),
                            subscription_item=sub_item,
                            action='increment')
                        form.save()

                        print("Last Ran: ", Sub_ID, amount)
                        all_custinfo_items = custinfo.objects.all()

                        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form, 'custinfo_items': all_custinfo_items})

    else:
        form = UsageForm()
#        all_subid_items = custinfo.objects.filter(Sub_ID__startswith='sub')
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It appears like you need to remove the _required_ attribute for your form fields. If you are using model forms, you would need to configure `null=True, blank=True` for the model field. Otherwise, you need to specify `required=False` for your form field. Your wish is desirable. However, you will need a full page refresh when you click the buttons.

Comment: Hey that worked. Thank you very much! Follow up question. Is it possible to have more than one form per view? Thinking it would be nice to have different fields passed through depending on what has been entered.

Comment: Absolutely, depending on your use case, it may be easier to modify the form via it's __init__ method, from there, you can conditionally render certain fields

Comment: oh interesting. I haven't used init yet. So I will have to get up to speed on that, but I like the idea of a dynamic form. I could have buttons up top that a user can select what they want to do and the form can change accordingly. Thank you again. I am starting to feel like a I getting traction in developing something useful after years of poking around at it. :-)